# Why does ggplot2 not show colours in mylegend?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I'm wondering why I don't get colors in my legend:

```
test=data.frame(a=1:6,b=7:12,c=13:18,d=rep(c("a","b"),each=3))
  ggplot() + 
  geom_line(data=test,aes(y=a,x= b,colour=d,group=d),size=1,alpha=0.5)+
  theme(legend.position="bottom") +
  xlab("x-axis")
```

I don't think this has happened before... has it got anything to do with my data?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of your alpha value. You can reset it for the legend like so:

```r
df <- data.frame(a=1:6,b=7:12,c=13:18,d=rep(c("a","b"),each=3))

library(ggplot2)

g <- ggplot()
g <- g + geom_line(data = df, aes(y = a, x = b, colour = d, group = d), 
                   size = 1, alpha = 0.5)
g <- g + theme(legend.position="bottom")
g <- g + xlab("x-axis")
g <- g + guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(alpha = 1)))

print(g)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-06-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>